# Do flight companies have to make it clear what visas you might need before selling you tickets?

Tags: visas, air-travel, legal

Is there any legal requirement for companies selling flight tickets to tell their customers what Visas they may need for the flight?

If they make it sound like, via omission, that you don't need any visas for a journey you do need visas for, and then take money in exchange for the tickets, have they committed any potential legal wrong?

Comment: Moot question: All airlines have terms and conditions (or a contract of carriage) that clearly state that proper documentation (for both entry and Corvid) is the traveler's responsibility. All airlines require you to accept these terms when you buy a ticket.

Comment: Your question is borderline with `law` stack exchange. In general you are responsible to be in line with laws (also if you do not know it). When you buy a ticket, usually there is a link to check visa requirements (usually on external site, because it is complex). In any case you should know better then an airline. If you want more, you should go to a travel agency.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi a real good travel agency. Many travel agencies won’t assist customers with that either (including of course the vast majority of online travel agencies).

Comment: In much the same way that it's not the Uber driver's responsibility to check that you have a valid flight ticket when they drive you to the airport, the airline doesn't have a responsibility *to you* to ensure that you have the correct documentation for your flight destination. The only reason the airline cares at all and checks your documentation at boarding is to reduce *their* risk of having to fly you back where you came from if you're denied entry.

Comment: @Hilmar: The EU for one takes a very dim view of companies that try to make consumers responsible for things that the company knows best. This burden cannot be shifted to the consumer, not even via a contract. A company can't tell you _exactly_ which visa you need, because it can depend on individual factors that the airline may not know. But general things like "transit visa are required for this layover" are more objective.

Comment: Why would they? How could that be their responsibility? Consider that in light of MSalters' Comment (above) which boils down to 'check for yourself' even though very clearly, MSalters isn't about to accept that.

Answer (score 37):

No, flight selling companies tell you that you need to look for the needed visa yourself.
That is airlines as well as sites that only sell the tickets.

There are even sites that sell a lot of unconnected flights, with very short layovers, where most people need visa, without a clear warning about this.

With the warning that it is on the customer to make sure they have the needed visa they cover the legal aspect. (But I think in some countries you might be able to argue that they should have done more and you may get a partial refund, but I have never heard of that happening.)

Comment: So if they don't say "check what visas you may need" then selling you the tickets may be illegal in some way?

Comment: @theonlygusti, they all have it somewhere on their site, in the paperwork they get you to sign if you buy in a brick and mortar travel agency and likely in the small print on the ticket themselves if they still hand out paper tickets.

Comment: Which jurisdictions does the last parenthesis in your answer pertain to?

Comment: As I wrote, I have never heard of one, so there might be but I can not tell you where to look for them.

Comment: As long as there are warnings somewhere that you need to ensure you have the proper travel documents for the trip, I doubt any sane legal system would hold the vendor liable in case the customer does not have said documents. It's impossible for the vendor after all to ensure said documents exist, unless they themselves provide them as part of the contract with the customer.

Comment: @theonlygusti What exactly do you mean by “illegal”? It’s not illegal to buy or own a ticket to a country you can’t legally enter, it’s just a waste of money.

Comment: @MikeScott: Pretty sure they mean defrauding the customer who bought the ticket, or otherwise tricking them into giving them money for a ticket they won't be able to use. For the carrier, that's a very profitable sale since they can see the same seat to someone else.

Answer (score 22):

Questions like that, or complains about specific cases where it did not happen, are common on this site. But think about what you are asking the ticket seller to do:

They would have to be aware of the **entire** travel and legal history of their customer, as well as all citizenships. A years-old overstay might mean that the customer cannot get a visa on arrival, and has to apply beforehand. A second or third citizenship might mean that the customer needs no visa. And even then, the customer might be on a *secret* no-fly list held by some country.

Or they hand out a pages-long questionnaire, with lots of questions that are either insulting ("have you ever been convicted of a crime of moral turpitude") or impossible to answer ("do you have the same birthdate and shoe size as a wanted terrorist?"). Then they feed that into a [computer system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) and tell the customer the answer.

For easy cases, it would actually be an option to require that from any ticket seller (travel agent, tour operator, ...). But it would also mean that people with complex cases would not be asked to think through their specific situation.

Comment: Unclear scenarios (like "hidden no flight lists") are obviously out of the question. But since all airlines DO check visas and passport at check in, there is no reason they can't do the same at sell point (online or offline).

Comment: @Dmitry, that's my 4th paragraph. With the comment in the second sentence of that paragraph.

Comment: Essentially nobody asks them to check my right of entry, only whether or not I'm allowed to board. In reality I can think only of one real issue. I could buy (and sometimes I have to!) my ticket even before I got my visa. That would be silly to forbid to sell a ticket to me in that case.

Comment: @Dmitry rules change. You being able to travel to country X via country Y on the date of purchase doesn’t mean you will be able to do so on the date of the flight (and vice versa). On date of purchase, customer may not yet have a visa (or even a passport), or an ESTA/ETA/eVisitor or whatever it’s called for the combination. If airlines start checking at time of purchase, it opens a big nasty Pandora’s box of liability for them if they ever got it wrong or anything changed in the meantime. Much better for them to put the responsibility squarely in the shoulders of the passenger.

Comment: also, it might not make sense to ask for the visa when selling the ticket because you might even need to buy the ticket first to include it in the visa application, as in some tourist visas

Comment: I would overall agree that it's one more way that airlines can use their power to their own benefit to deny boarding without having helped you know the risks,  but that it is kindof realistic to say they are only selling transportation and not travel consulting

Comment: @jcaron: I had to fly extremely last-minute to the US once. While I did have a valid ESTA, the only connection I could get on such short notice was via Canada. I literally  didn't even have my ticket yet as the train entered the airport and my eTA didn't get approved until minutes before boarding the plane. It would have been completely impossible to get all the immigration stuff sorted out before buying the ticket.

Comment: And note that even with the checking there's something of a minefield.  Consider one such mine that has caused multiple improperly denied boardings:  China's transit without visa option.  SFO -> PVG (5 days) -> NRT (4 hours) -> SFO.  Legal?  Yes--but only if you understand that this is a trip to Tokyo with a connection in Shanghai.  Try to enter the destination as China and the computer will deny it.  (China simply looks at SFO -> PVG -> NRT and doesn't care about the NRT -> SFO leg.)

Comment: @Dmitry conditions can also change between the time the ticket is purchased and the time it is used, often with no or very little warning. E.g. I book a trip to the US 6 months in advance, 2 months later the visa requirements for me change so I need a visa rather than just an ESTA. Would the person selling me the ticket be liable for that in your world?

Comment: @Dmitry: There is a massive difference between a bouncer who decides to let the person in front of them into the club, and asking that bouncer to confirm over the phone if they would let the caller in. The same is true of airlines whether you have the documentation versus them needing to figure out which documentation you need.

Answer (score 11):

It is strictly impossible for an airline to know for sure and in advance if you will be allowed into a country or even allowed to board.

While the general cases can be relatively easy, there are so many special cases and exceptions it’s not even funny, there’s a lot of information they don’t even have (like previous travel history), and authorities have discretionary power to reject anyone at the border, or for countries with bidirectional API (like the US), at time of boarding (the dreaded “DO NOT BOARD”).

Even without getting to that point, tools like Timatic have a few limited cases where they will say “no visa required” or “visa required”, and then tons of cases where they have long lists of conditions and exceptions and special cases which are not standardised enough that you can just enter data and get a verdict, you just get something a human must interpret (which is often not quite obvious), sometimes pages and pages long, and is sometimes subject to errors.

Add to that the fact that things change quite often, and you get a big mess, which airlines absolutely do not want to enter, as it could open them to a whole lot of liability. So they just stay clear and put the responsibility squarely on the shoulders of the passenger, and they honestly very little other choice.

Many airlines and OTAs will make it quite obvious and explicit at the time of purchase, but it is always spelled out in the terms and conditions.

Comment: and then there are the cases where you get stopped after checking in by some roving security patrol, taken in for questioning, and miss your flight. Would the ticket vendor be responsible? Obviously not. On take the case of my father who once in Budapest was taken off the aircraft after boarding by the secret police when his permanent entry business visa for the USA (tells how long ago that was, they no longer issue those) raised the suspicion of someone at security, they led him through but reported it anywyay.

Answer (score 5):

### You expect a higher level of customer service.

You have in your mind a certain level of attentiveness and customer service.  You want your provider to pay attention to details like that, and work with you to help your travel be a success.

That's fine and a reasonable thing to expect. **From a quality, full-service travel agent**.

And I remember when that was pretty much mandatory.  You didn't get on a plane without a machine-printed ticket exactly the size of an IBM card, with perforations and break-off sections, that came off a very expensive printer that the travel agent leased, and tied to a 3278 terminal on a special phone line.  As telephone call centers, automated phone systems and the Internet changed all that, legislators decided consumers should be free to choose discount providers.  Which works for me.

But now that such discount providers have become normalized, people don't realize a full-service agent is even a thing, or a thing for them because they prefer "cheaper".  True; agents don't work for free.

When you book travel yourself on the Internet, **you're the agent**, and it's your job to educate your client on travel issues like visas.  That's why you get the big bucks!   :) Or rather, keep the big bucks in your pocket.

So you chose to DIY the visa stuff when you decided to deal discount/direct. That was your choice and they don't owe you anything.